# Call api undefined in console.log

Tags: reactjs, api, console

I am using api to get and post data, when I am using fetch in console tab (F12), it working, but I integrate to my code, it return undefined in console tab, I go to Network tab in Chrome (F12), I choose Header tab, Preview or Response, it still shows respone such as I fetch in console. Why and how to fix this. Thank you all.

Comment: please add more details like your actual api call code and where do you do `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add more info, As per my guess you would have misused 'this' keyword in the call back. If that is the case you use 'bind' or es6 arrow function.